# Why does git difftool use git diff instead?

Tags: git, diff, config, vimdiff, meld

I want `git diff` to be a quick command line solution to see the difference between two files, and then I want `git difftool` to launch meld for a more graphical view of the file differences.

Currently, `git diff` does exactly what I want it to, however when I run `git difftool script.js`, git tries to launch vimdiff instead of meld:

```
Viewing (1/1): 'script.js'
Launch 'vimdiff' [Y/n]:
```

If I specify the tool with `git difftool -t meld script.js` it tries to launch meld as it should:

```
Viewing (1/1): 'script.js'
Launch 'meld' [Y/n]:
```

How do I get `git difftool <filename>` to launch meld while `git diff <filename>` still uses vimdiff?

My .gitconfig contains the following:

```
[diff]
     tool = vimdiff
[difftool]
    tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
    path = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\Meld.exe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git config --global diff.tool meld
```

This will set the default difftool to meld. I.e. when you invoke `git difftool` without the `--tool` parameter, git will run meld.

You can also remove that part of your config, git won't read `difftool.tool` as it's not [one of git's known config options](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

```
[difftool]
    tool = meld
```

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick, thank you!  But I don't quite understand what happened.  That command changed `[diff] tool=vimdiff` to `[diff] tool=meld`.  How does git know to use vimdiff for `git diff` when vimdiff is no longer specified anywhere in the .gitconfig?

Comment: Diff doesn't use vimdiff. AFAIK, git diff implements its own diff algorithm/way of displaying diffs in a shell.